# How do I follow up on the comments made in my site using Facebook comments plugin?

Tags: seo, facebook

I installed Facebook's social plugin - Comments.
I thought that it would encourage people to comment on my articles and by doing that I will get (at the end) more traffic.

After installing it to my site's articles, I found my self in a problem.
How do I follow up on the comments made in my site?

I have many articles and I don't understand, as a site owner, where do I see notifications on new comments. I need to make sure that I'm not spammed or that I need to comment on someone's question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you use a Facebook application ID? If you do, you should see a link under the comments box plug-in where you can administrate/moderate comments. I think there is an option there for you to ask to be notified of comments; I'm not sure about this because I haven't got as far as trying it out yet (because of what I say in the next paragraph) but it looks like that is what it does. You can get an app ID from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/setup/)

I should warn you first, though, at this point I am having a [problem with my comments plug-in](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5942/facebook-social-plugin-comments-disappear-from-my-drupal-site-after-using-faceboo) — I previously did not use an app ID and people left comments on my website without problem. After I got an app ID and started using it, all the previous comments have disappeared. Also, if I try to go back to not using an app ID the comments box will no longer load. I say this to you because I don't want you to start using an app ID and lose all your comments on your website

I am currently trying to find out if it is a "feature" of the Facebook platform (or the Drupal extension module I am using) or a bug. Please feel free to follow along with [my question on this forum](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5942/facebook-social-plugin-comments-disappear-from-my-drupal-site-after-using-faceboo) which will hopefully clarify the issue.